# Access Infinispan Server using HotRod C++ throws Exception

Tags: c++, infinispan

I am trying to access an Infinispan Server using HotRod library in C++ because I'm not familiar with Java but I got Exception and don't know how to proceed.

The source code is:

```
#include "infinispan/hotrod/ConfigurationBuilder.h"
#include "infinispan/hotrod/RemoteCacheManager.h"
#include "infinispan/hotrod/RemoteCache.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        infinispan::hotrod::ConfigurationBuilder cb;
        cb.addServer().host("192.168.1.1").port(11222);
        infinispan::hotrod::RemoteCacheManager cm(cb.build());
        infinispan::hotrod::RemoteCache<std::string, std::string> cache = cm.getCache<std::string, std::string>("dCache");
        cm.start();
        std::cout << cache.size() << std::endl;
        cm.stop();
        return 0;
}
```

and what I got is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'infinispan::hotrod::HotRodClientException'
  what():  scala.MatchError: 24 (of class java.lang.Byte)
Aborted
```

ps. GDB backtrace indicates the error is occurred on the line of `std::cout << cache.size() << std::endl;`.

Comment: This looks like a mismatch in protocol. What version of client and server do you use? Please check server log, the exception should be logged there with full stack trace.

Comment: @Flavius Client is 8.0.0.CR2 and server is 6.0.0.Final. I checked the server log and get a lot of things like `16:28:55,420 ERROR [org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodDecoder] (HotRodServerWorker-223) ISPN005003: Exception reported: org.infinispan.server.hotrod.RequestParsingException: Unable to parse header` and `ERROR [org.infinispan.server.hotrod.HotRodDecoder] (HotRodServerWorker-226) ISPN005009: Unexpected error before any request parameters read: scala.MatchError: 24 (of class java.lang.Byte)`

Comment: Does the server log say which version of protocol the client uses? C++ client should know only 1.2 and lower, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

C++ client version 8.0.0 uses by default the Hotrod protocol VERSION_24, that it's too new for Infinispan 6.0.0.

Try to configure VERSION_13 this way:

```
cb.addServer().host("192.168.1.1").port(11222).protocolVersion(Configuration::PROTOCOL_VERSION_13);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know HotRod C++ and I don't know if it's the cause of your exception but, according [this page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Data_Grid/6.6/html/API_Documentation/files/CPP/classinfinispan_1_1hotrod_1_1RemoteCacheManager.html),
the `RemoteCacheManager` constructors, by default, start the manager; so, the following `cm.start()` it's a second start (?).

In [this example](http://infinispan.org/docs/hotrod-clients/cpp/#_usage) I see that the manager is created without starting it, so...

Suggestion: try with

```
infinispan::hotrod::RemoteCacheManager cm(cb.build(), false);
```

Comment: I've modified that part but nothing changes.